# Where are clouds, stucci, wood textures in cycles materials?

Tags: texturing, materials

So I want to use the extra settings for the musgrave setting (where you can pick blender original or voronoi f2 etc.) in a material but it seems you can only use it in the texture panel. Is there any way of using these textures in materials?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger how do you use them then? They're not in the add node menu...

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger Not helpful, unless you're going to say *how* to access them.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I'm not sure how this post relates to my question. Do I need to make it more clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cycles is a completely different rendering engine, with its own system, separate settings, materials and different workflow. Blender internal materials and textures are not available under Cycles and the opposite is also true.

Cycles has it's own musgrave texture accessible through the node editor Add Menu > Textures > Musgrave. It has it's own set of settings and can be tweaked as just like Blender Internal.
You can even use other textures com combine, mix or deform the current one.

Comment: So to use the textures I'll have to render it in Blender Internal and use it as an image texture?

Comment: If you specifically want to use Blender Internal's Musgrave in cycles yes, that would be a possibility, render it as an image, or bake it using the desired UV Map. Otherwise you could try Cycles musgrave, unless you are looking for something very specific, it is not that different and most likely enough for what you want.